# How can convert string to date then subtract date in mongoose query?

Tags: sql, mongodb, date, mongoose

Can I subtract string to string with date format?

Example:

I have two fields: request and response (String format: yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss).

I have record:

```
{
_id: 1,
request: 2015/12/28 12:10:10,
response: 2015/12/28 12:10:15
}
```

and expect result:

```
{
_id: 1,
duration: 5
}
```

Can we convert string to date then using `$subtract` (aggregation) to subtract two value?

I try to search and found nothing yet.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show some sample documents and the expected output?

Comment: I just edited. You have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the string to date format you would have to iterate the results from a find() operation and update the collection within the loop:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id }, 
        {
            "$set": { 
                "request": new Date(doc.request), 
                "response": new Date(doc.response) 
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Perfomance with the above update operation can be compromised if dealing with large collections, however using the **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/)** can streamline the updates
for maximised efficiency by reducing the amount of update operations sent to the sever, sending once every 1000 queued operations:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

db.collection.find({
    "request": { "$exists": true, "$type": 2 }, 
    "response": { "$exists": true, "$type": 2 }
}).forEach(function(doc) {     
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "request": new Date(doc.request), 
            "response": new Date(doc.response) 
        }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clean up queues
if (counter % 1000 != 0){
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Having updated the fields to proper date formats, you can then run the following aggregation pipeline to get the desire results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "duration": { "$subtract": [ "$response", "$request" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: amazing! I try to. Meanwhile waiting your comment. I try getting data from database and handling duration in server.

Comment: @chridam: Can I ask you a question? It's can we aggregation a limit document? example: just aggregation 100 records first.

Comment: @user1697646 Yes, it's indeed possible. Use the [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#pipe._S_limit) pipeline operator.